# Error while compiling a GTK application on ubuntu 13.04 - missing headers

Tags: gtk, eclipse-cdt

I am developing a GTK application using the ECLIPSE IDE.

I am unable to build the application cause when I include file from `gtk/gtk-2.0/gtk.h` then it gives me a error that

```
`gdk/gdk.h` no such file or directory found ..
```

I tried to add the include directory path also but it is of no use.

Is there is any way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The gdk header file is part of the `libgtk2.0-dev` package, so you will need to install that before you can compile GTK applications. You can install it using apt.

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

While you're at it, you'll probably need the `build-essential` package too. It contains applications like g++, gcc and other standard headers.